# MoveNext error using async with Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, codeigniter-3, nusoap

I have a Xamarin Android forms project using a CodeIgniter back end, with NuSoap.

I visual studio I created a .NET core project for testing, added a connected service to the server.  Created a async task to pull the data from the server, this all worked correctly.

```
var client = new TbqService.ServicePortTypeClient();
var loginTask = Task.Run(() => client.logInAsync("user", "password"));
echoTask.Wait();
Console.WriteLine($"Login result {loginTask.Result}");
```

I then followed the same sequence for the Xamarin forms application but am getting the following error.  I have seen comments about setting the SSL to TLS 1.2 and removing the bin/obj folder and rebuilding.  Neither helped.

```
{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at MyThingApp.Models.DataConnect+<Login>d__13.MoveNext () [0x00023] in  
 D:\WebSites\TheMyThing_Projects\MyThingApp\MyThingApp\MyThingApp\Models\DataConnect.cs:31 }
```

Is there a different in the way the two work, should I be handling them differently?

```
    public async Task<bool> Login(string email, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var c = new TbqService.ServicePortTypeClient();
            var result = await c.logInAsync(email, password); // line 31 in error
            return result.Contains("true");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: what is line 31 of DataConnect,cs?

Comment: var result = await c.logInAsync(email, password);

Answer (score 0):

It seems like result might be returning null. And so it crashes when you are trying to access contents inside result. Add a null check, and that should remove you error.

```
if (result != null)
    return result.Contains("true");
```